# How can i get the channel from my interaction? (discord.js v14)

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

uh so in my code i want to make an "echo" command. basically everything works, but the bot sends it in the channel the interaction took place. i want the bot to send the message in the channel the user selected.

Heres my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, SlashCommandStringOption,  } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const {Client, GatewayIntentBits} = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('echo')
        .setDescription('Replies with your input!')
        .addStringOption(optione =>
            optione.setName('input')
                .setDescription('The input to echo back')
                .setRequired(true)

                
                )

                .addChannelOption(optionss => 
                    optionss.setName('channel')
                    .setDescription('which channel do u want')
                    .setRequired(true)
                    ),

                

                async execute(interaction) {
                    const input = interaction.options.getString("input")
                    interaction.reply({content: "Sent!", ephemeral:true})
                    interaction.channel.send(input)
                    
                } 
};
```

This makes it so lets say if i do the "/echo" command in general (but in the interaction i didnt choose general) the message would be sent in general. i dont want that.

Thanks in advance.

f i forgot there was this part, but yeah. i want it to send the message in the channel the user put.

i follow the documention and im like only about 5 days into learning, so im sorry if this is a really simple thing to fix.

i dont get any errors, just doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
interaction.channel.send(input)
```

indeed gets the channel the interaction comes from.

As per the [documentation for the interaction object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding), it should have a `message` property in these cases, which again would have the property `mention_channels`. Be mindful of the limitations of this property laid out in the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object). From there, you should get the `id` of the mentioned channel as `interaction.mention_channels.first().id`. You must then send a message in that channel, in your case it would be something like this:

```
client.channels.fetch(interaction.mention_channels.first().id).then(channel => channel.send(input))
```

Depending on your specific use-cases, perform null-checks etc. as required.

Comment: could you remoke the code completly? i replaced the `interaction.channel.send(input)`

with what u said, but it still doesnt work and im pretty confused ngl

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the options-part in your code. Try `interaction.options.getChannel("channel").id` instead of `interaction.mention_channels.first().id`.

Comment: still dont work. rip `if (interaction.commandName === "echo") {
   const input = interaction.options.getString("input")
                    interaction.reply({content: "Sent!", ephemeral:true})
                    interaction.channel.send(input)
                    client.channels.fetch(interaction.optionss.getChannel("channel").id).then(channel => channel.send(input))
  }`







Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChannel')

Comment: Hard to tell, but optionss may not be defined where you call it. In your original post it is only defined within addChannelOptions, so you can't use it where you tried to.

Comment: hey,

thanks for your help. i found a discord server that managed to help me. thanks tho!

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, please post it as an answer yourself to help people who have the same problem